# Unable to create any file or folder inside a directory without execute permission

Tags: shell, zsh

[my terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Pvk.png)

In the posted screenshot you can see that I've created a directory named 'test' and then removed its execute permission to check if I can create a directory or file inside it without this permission.

But to my surprise, I can't create anything inside this 'test' dir despite having write permissions.

Can anyone explain what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: It's better to post terminal output as text, rather than a screenshot. That way the question is clear from just the question text, and is also a bit more readable. As for your question: you need "executable" ("x") permissions to cd in to a directory. Yes, that's weird, but that's how it works 

Comment: Thanks @MartinTournoij for your comment. I now understand why I wasn't able to write files in the directory without execute permission. Also, I'll post outputs as text in the future.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux usage questions should be posted to [unix.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150449/what-does-execute-permission-mean-on-a-folder) helps.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the letters 'ugoa' controls which users' access to the file will be changed: the user who owns it (u), other users in the file's group (g), other users not in the file's group (o), or all users (a).

So in your case u-x :- you have removed permission for user(yourself as you are one who has created the folder) hence it can not create anything inside test folder.